# Call requires permission which may be rejected by user in android API 28

Tags: android

In my app I am trying to access the user's number in the following code:

```
public class TelephoneNumber {
    Context mContext;

    public TelephoneNumber(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public String getMyPhoneNumber() {
        String phone_number = "";
        try {
            phone_number = ((TelephonyManager) this.mContext.getSystemService("phone")).getLine1Number();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return phone_number;
    }
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with checkPermission) or explicitly handle a potential SecurityException less...

This check scans through your code and libraries and looks at the APIs being used, and checks this against the set of permissions required to access those APIs. If the code using those APIs is called at runtime, then the program will crash.  Furthermore, for permissions that are revocable (with targetSdkVersion 23), client code must also be prepared to handle the calls throwing an exception if the user rejects the request for permission at runtime
```

What do need to do?

Comment: The error tells you exactly what to do: you should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with checkPermission). More generally, you should read about the Android permissions model: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ask for permission explicitly if you want to handle newer APIs. After checking the users API you can ask for permission and continue with your code like that:

This would e.g. the part that is running after starting the application:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 111);
            }
        }
```

And for the response you use the `onRequestPermissionResult` method:

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 111:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //your code
                }
        }

    }
```

Comment: please I'm new to android, is there a way you could help with the code I pasted here? I tried your code but I was getting lots of errors.

Comment: I will try, I’ll have a look at it later in case the problem is still existing

Comment: @TonyeBoro have you followed this tutorial already? https://en.proft.me/2017/11/27/how-get-phone-number-programmatically-android/

Comment: thanks. I have been able to solve it with your code.